# Django Simple Search on Foreign Key and Many to Many Fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

[This snippet](http://julienphalip.com/post/2825034077/adding-search-to-a-django-site-in-a-snap) for a simple Django search works great but doesn't support searches on Foreign Key or Many to Many fields. How can I search FK and M2M?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the snippet, the magic happens here:

```
def get_query(query_string, search_fields):
    ...
    q = Q(**{"%s__icontains" % field_name: term})
    ...
```

Based on that, it appears that this *does* support FK or M2M searches, you just have to specify the full path in your `search_fields` string using the double underscore `__`.

---

For example, lets say you had a model `Task` which has a foreign key to `Project`, and `Project` has an attribute `name`:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

If you wanted to search through project names on `Task`, you would write the following:

```
>>> tq = get_query('<search term>',['project__name',])
>>> t = Task.objects.filter(tq)
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, I've been trying to put the full path in the wrong spot this whole time. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @plact - No problem. Do note the trailing comma in the search fields... that is required to ensure the `search_fields` variable remains a list rather than being converted to a string.